# unresolved external symbol __RTC *

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компоновщик

Опишите возможные причины проблемы линковки:

> main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __RTC_CheckEsp referenced in function _main
>
> main.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __RTC_Shutdown
>
> main.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __RTC_InitBase
>
> untitled.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
>
> LINK Pass 1 failed. with 1120

Просьба не предлагать ничего переустанавливать, так как тестирую произвольно настраиваемую Developer Command Prompt (тестирую с различными ключами и переменными среды).

Флаги такие:`cl /TP -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1`

SDK такое:`Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0`

В релизной конфигурации с ключем `/MD` и без ключа `/RTC1` проблем не возникает, при дебаге - см. выше.

Подскажите возможную причину(ы), с чего начинать искать и так далее...

Comment: Может быть, какой-то из obj-модулей скомпилирован с другими ключами? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007915/276994

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже на то, как если у одного модуля рантайм динамический, у другого - статический, или один модуль скомпилирован в отладочном режиме, а другой - в релизе.

Еще вариант - не подключена какая-то библиотека.

Comment: Скорее всего библиотека, но какая? А сама программа - это простенький однофайловый hello world.

Comment: Это скорее всего RunTimeCheck - функции в Visual C++, подключаемые при соответствующем ключе.

Comment: я уже ответил на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Проблему удалось решить так:
Добавил эти строки к линкеру:

> /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD.lib
>
> /DEFAULTLIB:J:/2/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/lib/Crt/i386/msvcrtd.lib
>
> /DEFAULTLIB:J:/2/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/lib/msvcrtd.lib

Убираем (`MSVCRTD.lib(msvcrtd.dll)`) (который идет по умолчанию в SDK), добавляем его опять же потом с помощью `/DEFAULTLIB` (можно без указания пути в приниципе), а далее добавляем его молодого собрата `(msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll))` с другой SDK, который может ресолвить все это `__RTC_CheckEsp`,  `__RTC_Shutdown`, `__RTC_InitBase`.

`helloworld` под дебагом собрался, дальше не тестировал, если кому интересно, вот [linker verbose.log](https://gist.github.com/goodandrewsoft/6e702101059066bbd00021f7f60d2a36)